# ASM Assembly code to create first 16 Fibonaaci numbers

Tags: assembly, avr, microprocessors

I'm looking to create the first 16 fibonacci numbers in ASM assembly code and store them in my microprocessor starting from location 0x300
I have

```
ldi r16, 0  #load register 16 with 0
ldi r17, 1
add r17, r16  
mov r18, r17
sts 0x300, r18  #store first number in 0x300
mov r16, r17
mov r17, r18
rjmp loop
```

My issues are how do I stop after 16 numbers & how to store each number in 0x301, 0x301...0x315
I am unclear as what to put after mov r17, r18 to increment 0x300 to 0x301 and enable count

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you aid?

Answer (score 1):

@stop after 16
try to add a counter

```
   ldi r20,16 #loop counter
start:
...#your loop body
dec r20
brne start
```

@how to store each number in 0x301,
Read about "indirect addressing"
There is a X indirect register:

> X,Y,Z: Indirect Address Register (X=R27:R26, Y=R29:R28 and Z=R31:R30)
>   so you should put your address in X, and use "st X+,Rr"

```
clr r26 #this is lower 00 from 0x300
ldi r27,3 #this is higher 3 from 0x300 and here you've got X set to 0x300
...#some of your code
st x+,r18 #where r18 got data to be stroed in memory. x will be increased automaticly
```